# (my)SQL database - storing different types of same value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jpa, types

I need to store different types of same value. The Value can represent DATE, INT, BOOLEAN, DOUBLE and any other type. I'm wondering if it is possible **not using** multiple tables - each for different type (I suppose that it would significantly complicate usage of stored Values (mainly searching, filtering)). Would it be a big storage and performance degradation when storing multiple column table with mainly NULL values in a row?

I'm thinking of table with such example columns from which only one value column will be filled:

```
id valueVarchar  valueDate  valueBoolean  valueInt  valueDouble
```

If that approach is clearly wrong please enlighten me.

I'm creating JSF application using MySQL (InnoDB) (database is not a big issue, it can be changed if necessary) and JPA.

**edit:**

As for now I have one table with one text value field. I'm converting values to/from database on server side. Because the project has just recently been started and changing model now will be less painful than in the future, I'm considering existence of better approach.

Comment: **Why** do you need to store the same value as multiple different types - what do you hope to achieve by doing so? Why would a specific value potentially have multiple different types?

Comment: It is a little confusing; if you are attempting to do this because of the varying types this one value can be, then I would suggest using VarChar; as there are conversion functions which exist to convert it to the other data types.

Comment: @MarkBannister: off the top of my head: an enterprise may have applications/contexts that use different values for pi e.g. as a float and as a fixed decimal. Also perhaps different rounding algorithms e.g. truncated at 3 d.p., banker's rounding to 3 d.p. etc.

Comment: @MarkBannister: I'm creating annotation system in which I'm linking some object with many attributes - these can be of any type. Attribute has one meaningful field - value. I was considering different approaches but I'm not database person so I'm looking for advice ;]

Comment: @MattDonnan That is what I have now but I'm worried if it won't trouble me in the future.

Comment: @jkbkrk It would really depend on how and where you are going to use the conversions, the less you use the better to reduce work on the server but on the whole they shouldn't dramatically slow down any SQL queries; but again dependent on the complexity.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using EclipseLink, you can use a @TypeConverter to convert any data-type to String.  You could also have two column one for the value and one for the value's type, you could map this using an @Transformation mapping.

With generic JPA you could transform the type through get/set methods using property access.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will familiarize myself with it.

Comment: I would think that the OP's original design is a bit better than this one. Storing different datatypes in same column is not a good use of the DB.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, it appears that it is intended that for each **entity**, each **attribute** will have its **value** stored separately.

There is a name for this: it is called the [Entity-Attribute-Value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model), or EAV for short.

Although there are situations in which EAV is the only applicable solution, its use is generally regarded as an anti-pattern where viable alternatives are available.

A case study of an inappropriate implementation of an EAV database can be found [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/).

One of the most obvious purposes for which EAV can be used is for the persistence of Object data from OO designs, in relational databases. If this is how you want to use it, I urge you to consider [Object-Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (ORM for short) instead.

You can find EAV-related questions on SO using the [eav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eav) tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can store anything as a binary value, and cast to the type at client side. But the value can hardly be efficiently used within query conditions.